# Using recursion to search through a binary tree and check if it contains a string

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I am attempting to use recursion to search through a binary tree and return true or false depending on if the binary tree contains the string. Here is my code

```
public class BinaryTree {
private String data;
private BinaryTree leftChild;
private BinaryTree rightChild;

public BinaryTree() {
    data = null;
    leftChild = null;
    rightChild = null;
}

public BinaryTree(String d) {
    data = d;
    leftChild = new BinaryTree();
    rightChild = new BinaryTree();
}

// This constructor is unchanged
public BinaryTree(String d, BinaryTree left, BinaryTree right) {
    data = d;
    leftChild = left;
    rightChild = right;
}

// Get methods
public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public BinaryTree getLeftChild() {
    return leftChild;
}

public BinaryTree getRightChild() {
    return rightChild;
}

// Set methods
public void setData(String d) {
    data = d;
}

public void setLeftChild(BinaryTree left) {
    leftChild = left;
}

public void setRightChild(BinaryTree right) {
    rightChild = right;
}

 public boolean contains(String d) {
    return d != null && (this.getData().equals(d) ||
            contains(this.getLeftChild().getData()) ||
            contains(this.getRightChild().getData()));
}
```

So, my issue is with the contains method as it keeps giving me a stackoverflow.error . I was hoping i could get assistance on this thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters, your recursion isn't recursing on the right data.  Instead of `contains(this.getLeftChild().getData())` you should be calling `this.getLeftChild().contains(d)`  You're not passing the query string to your child objects, you're passing the data on your child to the query on your root object, so your recursive call isn't asking "does my child's data contain this string?", instead it's asking "Does my data contain my child's data?"

Comment: what @rdowell said, but don't forget to check that `getLeftChild()` doesn't return `null` before trying to call its `.contains` method.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
public boolean contains(String d)
{
  // Not contained if specified string is null
  if (d == null)
    return (false);

  // OK if specified string equals our data
  if ((data != null) && data.equals(d))
    return (true);

  // OK if contained in left tree
  if ((leftChild != null) && leftChild.contains(d))
    return (true);

  // OK if contained in right tree
  if ((rightChild != null) && rightChild.contains(d))
    return (true);

  // Otherwise, it's not OK
  return (false);

} // contains
```

Comment: right idea, although I personally wouldn't use the accessors within the class's own methods - it's overhead that serves no useful purpose and will just make the code slower.

Comment: I agree. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

On each recursive call `this` refers to the **same object** and hence you keep on passing the same values over and over again. You need to pass `BinaryTree` references as a parameter.

```
private boolean contains(String data, BinaryTree node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return false;
    }

    return node.getData().equals(data) || contains(data, node.getLeftChild())
         || contains(data, node.getRightChild());

}
```

The main (public) `contains` needs to pass the String to be searched and the root to the above method.

Comment: this is absolutely *not* the way to check a node because the `contains` method already has a reference to the node that's being queried - it's `this`.   What you've proposed is how you'd do this in a non-OO language.

Comment: @Alnitak I don't get what you are saying. What if you move to a subtree? You need to access the node value (and its subtree references) using the getters

Comment: what of it?  The subtree has the _exact same methods_ as the root of the tree.   Take a look at Robert Kock's answer.

Comment: @Alnitak I'm not calling the contains method on the child node - I'm using recursion. You mean to access it directly like `node.leftChild`?

Comment: I'm talking about your passing of `node` as an explicit parameter.   You don't need to - the `contains` method has an implicit `node` passed as its `this` variable.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes. But how will you call the contains method recursively for the left/right node from here on without passing it?

Comment: @Alnitak Robert Kock's solution is not recursive. I'm focussing on recursive one as the OP got stuck on that approach

Comment: the other solution absolutely is recursive.   You don't have to *pass* it because you can call `leftChild.contains(d)` at which point you *have* made a recursive call *and* passed the child node as the implicit `this` parameter to that call.

Comment: @Alnitak Calling `leftChild.contains(d)` is not recursive. You have to call the `contains` method on the current object. The contains method you invoke is on some other object `leftChild` in what you tell

Comment: That's a completely incorrect definition of recursion.

Comment: @Alnitak Can you point a source that claims to call a method on *different object*  (of same type) as recursion

Comment: Can you point to one that shows your definition is correct?  Semantically calling a "method of a different object" and "passing that object as a parameter" are identical w.r.t recursion; the "current object" `this` is effectively just passed as a hidden parameter.    But in an OOP language passing that variable _explicitly_ is bad design.

Comment: @Alnitak But I'm not calling a "method on a different object". I'm calling the same method with different references each time. So, still I cannot correlate what you say with this

Comment: No, the other guy is calling the (same) method on a different object, and you claimed that's not recursion.  You're wrong, because that "different object" is part of the same (recursively defined) structure.

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing there is not recursion. You are asking:

```
boolean found = tree.contains(candidate)
```

right?

Your code expands this to

```
boolean found = candidate != null && (tree.getData.equals(d) || LEFT || RIGHT)
```

where LEFT is

```
contains(tree.getLeftChild().getData())
```

which is not comparing the candidate string with the left data at all but rather expands to

```
candidate != null && (tree.getData.equals(candidate) || LEFT || RIGHT)
```

which results in an endless loop, causing the StackOverflow.

You should reformulate the class as

```
public class Node {
    Node left, right;
    String data
    public boolean contains(String d);
}
```

and then your tree would be a root Node and the search could be recursive.